# How to get error text from Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: formulas, google-sheets, google-docs

Is there any way to get an error text from the formula in Google Spreadsheets?

For ex., I see the following error -

```
Ошибка
В диапазоне функции VLOOKUP значение "zzz" не найдено.
```

(the value 'zzz' not found)

I would like to extract 'zzz' from the error text.

I can not refer to the cell text, since the formula here looks like

```
=JOIN(", ";ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(A1;" ");'mapping table'!A:B;2;FALSE)))
```

Upd. here is the sample table - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gsY68pmymEUzVWZm8z5G5zuShWzkBEt3Y1Wbsu0jtZs/edit?usp=sharing, the expected value is given in cell D1. I would like to get it from the error text.

Comment: It sounds like cell `A4` contains search keys, and you want to return search results, or if there is no match, the search key itself. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)? Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: @doubleunary,  I've updated the question and added the sample spreadsheet there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iferror()` to catch the value that causes an error, like this:

`=arrayformula( textjoin(", "; true; iferror( left( vlookup( split(A1; " "); 'mapping table'!A1:B; 2; false ); 0 ); split(A1; " ") ) ) )`

Comment: Thanks. In my sample table your formula returns `value1, value2, zzz, value3`, when I need to get just `zzz`.

Comment: Edited the answer per your requirements.

Comment: Wow! Many thanks!